# absolute center text in responsive background

Tags: html, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I need text centered vertically and horizontally. I'm making a link with circle background, I need it responsive, and cannot set the line-height to the height of link. Here's why:

**html**

```
<a class="Previous" href="#"> < </a>
<a class="Next" href="#"> > </a>
```

**css**

```
a.Previous, a.Next {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 8%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 8%;
    margin: 0 2% 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have tried

```
line-height: 0;
```

It does not work. How do I get my text absolute centered inside of the link's responsive background?

Comment: If you are happy with the browser support I suggest you look at a flexbox solution. - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align` CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box. Meaning, you need to declare the anchors to display as a `table-cell` to use `vertical-align`.

Try changing `display: inline-block` to `display: table-cell`. You will also need to remove the float and change the parent to display as a table (or add a new parent around the anchors with a `display:table` on it.)

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myPTU/2/

Keep in mind, this will get you the desired result of the text being centered both vertically and horizontally, it may disrupt how the anchor is positioned on the page. You will likely need to rework style for the parent elements until you get your desired result.

---

Side note: You should encode your greater-than and less-than characters between the `<a>` tags as `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

For example:

```
<a class="Previous" href="#"> &lt; </a>
<a class="Next" href="#"> &gt; </a>
```

Comment: the side note was definitely appreciated Michael, thanks